# Why do my if/else statement not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I can't see why my if/else statement is not working correctly?

JavaScript

```
var month_games = "Games";
var month_hit = "Hit";
var month_stake = "Stake";
var month_profit = "Profit";
var games_month = 0;
var hit_month = 0 + "%";
var stake_month = 0;
var profit_month = 0;

$( document ).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById("Games_Month").innerHTML = month_games;
    document.getElementById("Hit_Month").innerHTML = month_hit;
    document.getElementById("Stake_Month").innerHTML = month_stake;
    document.getElementById("Profit_Month").innerHTML = month_profit;
});


$('#January').click(function(){ 
    if ($('#Games_Month').innerHTML = month_games)
      {$('#Games_Month').innerHTML = games_month;}
    else {$('#Games_Month').innerHTML = month_games;}
});
```

HTML

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr id="January">
      <th>January</th>
      <th id="Games_Month"></th>
      <th id="Hit_Month"></th>
      <th id="Stake_Month"></th>
      <th id="Profit_Month"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Now, when I click on `#january`, I would like the inner.HTML of the other ID's to change to what another variable is, but when clicked again, to change it back.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: because jQuery has no `innerHTML` ?

Comment: `=` is assignment operator, you should use `==` or `===` as equality operator in the `if` statement

Answer (score -1, accepted):

jQuery has no `innerHTML`, it has `html()` instead.

A single `=` is assigment, two `==` is non-strict comparison, three `===` is strict comparison.

There's no need for the if/else here at all, just use the proper methods, like `html()` with a callback

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    var stake_month  = 0;
    var profit_month = 0;
    var month_games  = "Games";
    var month_hit    = "Hit";
    var month_stake  = "Stake";
    var month_profit = "Profit";
    var games_month  = 0;
    var hit_month    = 0 + "%";

    $("#Games_Month").html(month_games);
    $("#Hit_Month").html(month_hit);
    $("#Stake_Month").html(month_stake);
    $("#Profit_Month").html(month_profit);

    $('#January').click(function(){ 
         $('#Games_Month').html(function(_, html) {
              return html === month_games ? games_month : month_games;
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: Ended up using this example as it fills less, it works perfectly, thanks. May I ask if it is able to use this with classes instead of html?

Comment: @ShrekTek - Sure, jQuery's `addClass` and `removeClass` supports callbacks as well, but the syntax may vary a little bit.

Comment: Should I do the same as in this example? Like wrapping the classes into variables & call it that way?

Comment: Depends on how you intend to use it, it's hard to answer specifically how you should do it, without knowing what "it" is. Try asking it as a new question perhaps ?

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten the second `=` in the if, and it is `html()` not `innerHTML` there, because you got a jQuery object there, not a DOM element.

```
$('#January').click(function() { 
    if( $('#Games_Month').html() == month_games ) {
        $('#Games_Month').html(games_month);
    }
    else {
        $('#Games_Month').html(month_games);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! works perfectly now :) I'm a bit new at using both javascript & JQuery